# Getting session variable's value in meteorjs

Tags: meteor

When I set the session variable using

```
Session.set('location',position);
```

After its set, when I try

```
Session.get('location')
```

through console, I get an empty object

I have even added session using

```
meteor add session
meteor add constellation:session
```

But still it does not give any value even after it sets its value

I have used it like:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallbk);
});

successCallbk = function(position) {
    Session.set('location',position);
};
```

the position param received within successCallbk method, has a valid value, but that does not get retained in the location session var

Comment: is position valid value ? (not undefined)

Comment: ya, I have edited it with the exact usage. It has a valid value, not undefined.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Coming from a Tutorial on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Try hardcoding it first.

Session.set('testSession', 'This is a test')

Setup the Session.Get for your template.

See if you can get it to display in a template. Go into the browser console and set the session to something else and see if it works.

If this works you may have to give us more code to look over.

Answer (score 0):

Session provides a global object on the client that you can use to store an arbitrary set of key-value pairs. Use it to store things like the currently selected item in a list.

You should try verify if you are on the client side:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallbk);
  });
  successCallbk = function(position) {
    Session.set('location',position);
  };
};
```

Comment: already this js file is in client folder, also, even if i verify if its client and perform those, it still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very long time since you posted this question but I decided since I was using Josh's videos for references with Meteor, I'd post my solution:

```
success = function(position) {
    Session.set('location', {
        'coords': {
            'accuracy': position.coords.accuracy,
            'latitude': position.coords.latitude,
            'longitude': position.coords.longitude
        },
        'timestamp': position.timestamp
    });
}
```

Basically, I just copied the objects values that were important to me from the position object. It works as expected now. 
For Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iqdkVwtuvg